# Use Powershell to configure PowerPivot Data Refresh Schedules

Tags: powershell, powerpivot, data-refresh

Is there a way via powershell to check and see which items have a data refresh schedule configured for them? and If they don't proceed to create one? I can't seem to find much on working with powerpivot items using powershell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out in order to create a new data refresh schedule there is a stored procedure in the PowerPivot Service Application Database called 'Persist Schedule'. Using this proc you can pass in the appropriate parameters and create the schedule.

```
exec [DataRefresh].[PersistSchedule] 
@ItemID='B456AFE2-D44F-4DF2-AE1A-33511C8EE7B0',
@ItemName=N'FileName.xlsx',
@SPSiteID='EB7E69CC-68C5-4B90-81A8-D95F63892A0F',
@SPWebID='29036841-3DFD-4EEA-A648-271E4C98FCEC',
@LastModifiedBy=N'DOMAIN\username',
@ScheduleLastUpdatedBy=N'DOMAIN\username',
@UserIdentity=NULL,
@EmailNotification=1,
@EmailList=N'DOMAIN\username',
@SecurityConfiguration=0,
@SSApplicationID=NULL,
@ProcessAllDataSources=1,
@RV=NULL,
@Enabled=1,
@NextProcessDate='2015-04-01 00:00:00',
@ScheduleStartDate='2015-04-01 15:40:19.837',
@FrequencyKey=N'P',
@RepeatFrequency=1,
@Sunday=0,
@Monday=0,
@Tuesday=0,
@Wednesday=0,
@Thursday=0,
@Friday=0,
@Saturday=0,
@Weekday=0,
@WeekendDay=0,
@Day=0,
@MonthlyPeriod=0,
@MonthlySpecificDay=0,
@ProcessAfterBusinessHours=1,
@SpecificTime=NULL,
@RunNow=1
```

Answer (score 0):

their is not too much in powershell for the PowerPivot. Especially related to schedule.

But their is a hacking way which is by the way **NOT supported** and note recommended for the Production farm.

In the PowerPivotServiceApplication database, you will see these two tables.

- DataRefresh.Items
- DataRefresh.Runs

The “Items” table holds each published PowerPivot workbook. The “Runs” tables holds the PowerPivot scheduled refreshes. In short; when adding a PowerPivot workbook registered in the “Items” table to the “Runs” table with status “W” (waiting) it will be run the next time the SharePoint job scans the table.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c2551609-5b54-46e1-a31c-05736ef9bc90/programmatically-create-a-powerpivot-data-refresh-job-in-sharepoint?forum=sqlkjpowerpointforsharepoint

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/739949/powerpivot-2008-2012-for-sharepoint-data-refresh-more-than-once-a-day

[Everything You Always Wanted to Know About PowerPivot Data Refresh but Were Afraid to Ask](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff976569.aspx)